# Split content into two columns - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, split, implode

I have a custom meta box called 'list-two' (using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/)) and I'd like to use the 'more' tag within the editing pane to split the text/content into two columns. This is my code so far but only does half of what I need it to do:

In my functions.php file:

```
function split_morecontent() {
global $morecontent;
$morecontent = true;
$copy = preg_split('/<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>/i', get_field('list_two'));
for($c = 0, $csize = count($copy); $c < $csize; $c++) {
    $copy[$c] = apply_filters('list_two', $copy[$c]);
}
return $copy;
}
```

In my post template file:

```
<?php
 // split text into array
    $copy = split_morecontent();
 // output first content section in column1
echo '<section class="split">', array_shift($copy), '</section>';
 // output remaining content sections in column2
echo '<section class="split">', implode($copy), '</section>';
?>
```

Outputs the following HTML when run (notice its not actually splitting the content into the two  tags):

```
<section class="split">
  <ul class="footnote">
     <li>Christopher Gray</li>
     <li>Jean Jullien<!--more--></li>
     <li>Nous Vous</li>
     <li>Liv Bargman</li>
     <li>Luke Drozd</li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section class="split">
     <!-- the last 3 <li> tags from the list above should be displayed within here.-->
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way to do it is via jQuery. It's quite simple.
Use this: [Columnizer jQuery Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)

it works something like this:

```
$('.post-content').columnize({ columns: 2 });
```

And in your loop just place the_content() inside the div post-content

```
<div class="post-content">
  <?php the_content() ?>
</div>
```

Hope that's helpful for someone else ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's an article over at SitePoint that seems like it may help you out.  [Check out How to Split WordPress Content Into Two or More Columns](http://www.sitepoint.com/split-wordpress-content-into-multiple-sections/).  Basically, it tells you to do the following:

Add to your `functions.php`:

```
// split content at the more tag and return an array
function split_content() {
    global $more;
    $more = true;
    $content = preg_split('/<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>/i', get_the_content('more'));
    for($c = 0, $csize = count($content); $c < $csize; $c++) {
        $content[$c] = apply_filters('the_content', $content[$c]);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Wherever you want this division to occur (I am assuming `single.php` by default for most themes) you'll need to replace `the_content()` call with your newly created `split_content()`, like so:

```
<?php
    // original content display
        // the_content();
    // split content into array
        $content = split_content();
    // output first content section in column1
        echo '<div id="column1">', array_shift($content), '</div>';
    // output remaining content sections in column2
        echo '<div id="column2">', implode($content), '</div>';
?>
```

You now have the content split into two separate divs.  Just give them each a width and apply a float to them, and you will your content separated into two columns using the `<!--more-->` tag.

Comment: Yeah thats the code I'm trying to edit. Basically the code from Sitepoint will only split the_content. I'm trying to adapt it to split another WYSIWYG content box (that i've called list_two) but can't get it to work. So I need SitePoint's code to work with an additional WYSIWYG editor on the post editing page. Any ideas how I may do that?